# Use dynamic pattern to match numbers

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to write a query to show all items from schedule table that are scheduled for today.

The "day_string" column in the table can be * (meaning every day), a number (EG 5 meaning order only on the 5th of each month), a series of numbers (1,12,24 meaning only order on the 1st, 12th, and 24th of each month) or something like (1,2-5,7-11,19 which is equivalent to 1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,11,19).

How do I join against that table when to_char(sysdate,'fmDD') in that column?

Answer (score 3):

You could split the comma-separated string into individual rows using any common technique; here with a hierarchical query:

```
select id, regexp_substr(day_string, '(.*?)(,|$)', 1, level, null, 1) as days
from your_table
connect by id = prior id
and level <= regexp_count(day_string, ',') + 1
and prior sys_guid() is not null
```

to get:

```
ID DAYS
-- -----
 1 *
 2 5
 3 1
 3 12
 3 24
 4 1
 4 2-5
 4 7-11
 4 19
```

And then split the ranges into from/to values:

```
with cte1 (id, days) as (
  select id, regexp_substr(day_string, '(.*?)(,|$)', 1, level, null, 1)
  from your_table
  connect by id = prior id
  and level <= regexp_count(day_string, ',') + 1
  and prior sys_guid() is not null
)
select id,
  regexp_substr(days, '(.*?)(-|$)', 1, 1, null, 1) as days_from,
  regexp_substr(days, '(.*?)(-|$)', 1, 2, null, 1) as days_to
from cte;
```

```
ID DAYS_FROM DAYS_TO
-- --------- -------
 1 *
 2 5
 3 1
 3 12
 3 24
 4 1
 4 2         5
 4 7         11
 4 19
```

And then see if the current day of the month matches, against `*`, or numerically between the from/to values, using coalesce to filling in blank tot values to match from:

```
with cte1 (id, days) as (
  select id, regexp_substr(day_string, '(.*?)(,|$)', 1, level, null, 1)
  from your_table
  connect by id = prior id
  and level <= regexp_count(day_string, ',') + 1
  and prior sys_guid() is not null
),
cte2 (id, days_from, days_to) as (
  select id,
    regexp_substr(days, '(.*?)(-|$)', 1, 1, null, 1),
    regexp_substr(days, '(.*?)(-|$)', 1, 2, null, 1)
  from cte1
)
select *
from cte2
where days_from = '*'
or extract(day from sysdate) between to_number(days_from)
  and to_number(coalesce(days_to, days_from))
```

which gives (today, the 9th):

```
ID DAYS_FROM DAYS_TO
 1 *
 4 7         11
```

Or using inline views instead of CTEs:

```
select *
from (
  select id,
    regexp_substr(days, '(.*?)(-|$)', 1, 1, null, 1) as days_from,
    regexp_substr(days, '(.*?)(-|$)', 1, 2, null, 1) as days_to
  from (
    select id, regexp_substr(day_string, '(.*?)(,|$)', 1, level, null, 1) as days
    from your_table
    connect by id = prior id
    and level <= regexp_count(day_string, ',') + 1
    and prior sys_guid() is not null
  )
)
where days_from = '*'
or extract(day from sysdate) between to_number(days_from)
  and to_number(coalesce(days_to, days_from))
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2b8429a9dad0c54bd2eacd7fc314ea78)

I've just passed an arbitrary ID value through but you can include any data you want from the source table (as long as there is a unique field for the `connect by`, if you use that method).

Comment: I used your logic and regexp_substr statements, but turned it into a with function so that the query itself it easier to read.   Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Alex's answer, I ended up adding a function:

```
with 
function number_in_list(num1 in number, string1 in varchar2)
return varchar2 is
begin
if string1 = '*' then return 'true'; end if;
if regexp_like(string1, '[^0-9,\-]') then return 'oops'; end if;
for i in  (SELECT trim(regexp_substr(string1, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)) l
     FROM dual
       CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count(string1, ',')+1
     )
     LOOP
        if i.l is null then return 'false'; end if;
        if i.l like '%-%' then
            if to_number(regexp_substr(i.l, '(.*?)(-|$)', 1, 1, null, 1)) = num1 then
              return 'true';
            end if;
            if to_number(regexp_substr(i.l, '(.*?)(-|$)', 1, 2, null, 1)) = num1 then
              return 'true';
            end if;
            if num1 > to_number(regexp_substr(i.l, '(.*?)(-|$)', 1, 1, null, 1)) and num1 < to_number(regexp_substr(i.l, '(.*?)(-|$)', 1, 2, null, 1)) then
              return 'true';
            end if;
        elsif num1 = i.l then return 'true'; end if;
     END LOOP;
     return 'false';
end;
```

Which I can use like:

```
select * from schedule
where number_in_list(to_char(sysdate, 'fmdd'), day_string) = 'true'
```